# Facebook PHP SDK Redirection loop on simple login script on localhost

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Iam trying to implement a Facebook login with the Facebook PHP SDK. I can easily get to the facebook dialog for authorisation BUT after that, a redirection loop starts and i can see my browser attempt to connect to facebook then back to my localhost and back to facebook...until my browser finally gives me

> This webpage has a redirect loop

With this link hanging in the address bar

> [https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMY_APP_NAME%2Ffbconfig.php&state=acd9a0da2b78dasasasasasase1469d&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.15&scope=#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMY_APP_NAME%2Ffbconfig.php&state=acd9a0da2b78dasasasasasase1469d&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.15&scope=#_=_)

Iam trying to run the example on [this page](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/#comment-1599215609)
Here is the file that is handling the Facebook PHP SDK login operation.

**fbconfig.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'MY APP ID ','`MY SECRET' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/myappname/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

So this file sets ITSELF as the loginredirectionURL, but since the session is NEVER being created, the file calls it self again and again and again.

I just don't understand why the session is not being created. My App Domain and Site URL settings must be ok since iam getting to the Facebook authorization dialog without any URL errors. I can smoothly grant the app permissions but after the Facebook dialog goes away, i get no feedback, just a redirection loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Advanced panel from Settings in your app be sure your filled the label 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs'.
And try to use 2 files, one for log in and second for the redirect one.

A sample that i used to test:
1.php

```
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('$url',$facebook_id,$facebook_id_secret);
    echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with fb</a>';
```

2.php

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $facebook_id,$facebook_id_secret );
    $redirect_url = $url;
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
    if ($session) {
        echo 'logged in';
    }
```

Where $url is the url set by you in Settings/Advanced.

I hope this was useful.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, its now working smoothly after filling in a Valid OAuth redirect URIs..I just don't understand why this is not mentioned in any of the tutorials i was reading on this SDK...

Comment: You are welcome, i forgot where i found that. i started to learn facebook php sdk yesterday, so good luck !